# GlusterFS: Permissions for brick

Tags: glusterfs

When setting up a GlusterFS what are the requirements for the brick i.e. the directory on the gluster server in terms of

- permissions
- ownership

I know that gluster is [fully POSIX-compliant](https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Access%20Control%20Lists/) but I was wondering how the brick on each server shall be configured so that the gluster volume is usable by a gluster client. Currently my bricks are configured as this:

```
# ls -l /data/gluster/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 86 Dec 30 19:54 brick1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial permissions and ownership are not very relevant for the bricks. Once a client mounts and uses the volume, permissions/ownership set through the mountpoint will be reflected on the bricks. The settings should be the same on all bricks, or can be (re)set after mounting the volume.

Bricks should be a directory on a POSIX complaint filesystem with support for extended attributes. XFS is commonly used.

Comment: But somehow it still matters!? If the brick directory only has read permissions for the owner then also when mounting the directory nobody can write into the gluster volume?

Comment: Yes, if the owner is `papanito:papanito` and permissions are read-only, only `root` would be allowed to change it. This is just like with any other/local filesystem.